# Bootstrap 16 columns with 12 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have customized my bootstrap to 16 colums. It works great but.. I have a container with 1 column 4 and the other columns is 12. My problem is when I build columns in the column with 12 I can build again with 16colums.. I dont want that, I want 12 columns in a column with 12.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 well"></div>
<div class="col-sm-12 well">
    <!-- Blocks -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 menu-blocks"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 menu-blocks"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 menu-blocks"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 menu-blocks"></div>
    <!-- I want it to be 4x3. I am building on a 16grid column. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your CSS, can you put the code here please? Since we can't see what the actual problem here is.

Comment: I added some code, I am building on a 16 grid, but when I use a 12column i want it to be a 12 column grid.

Comment: How did you get to 16 cols. Are you using nesting, or a custom Bootstrap grid build?

Comment: I changed on the bootstrap website 12 to 16.

Answer (score 0):

How does this look in your implementation?
Wrapping it in a 'row' div might make the 12 cols fill.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 well"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 well">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Blocks -->
        <div class="col-sm-4 menu-blocks"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 menu-blocks"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 menu-blocks"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 menu-blocks"></div>
        <!-- I want it to be 4x3. I am building on a 16grid column. -->
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT= edit corresponding to OP's edit

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<div class="col-sm-12 well">` to `<div class="col-sm-16 well">` if you're using 4 columns of 4 blocks.

Also, you can't do what you're saying, as you can't have an implementation where a block has a width of both 8.33%(100/12) and 6.25%(100/16). It has to be one or the other.

Alternatively, you can have this implementation:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 well"></div>    <!-- column with 25% width -->
<div class="col-sm-12 well">         <!-- column with 75% width -->
    <!-- Blocks -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 menu-blocks"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 menu-blocks"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 menu-blocks"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 menu-blocks"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<div class="row"></div>` is important.

Here you have a grid inside the larger column, and the grid is of 12 blocks in both cases. To have a 4x3 grid you'll have to have three rows.

Remember, the 3 and 12 are the number of Bootstrap blocks, and they're relative to the rows(`<div class="row"></div>`), not the outer container.

Comment: I think OP is using a [custom Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables-section) build__ changing the `@grid-columns` var to 16

Comment: @Skelly Oh, I didn't know that could be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it back to 12 once you've customized it to 16. The closest you can get to a full width 3 cols wide in the 16 col grid would be to use 3 `col-*-5` (3x5=15) and then offset the first column..

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
       <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 menu-blocks">
                1
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-5 menu-blocks">
                2
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-5 menu-blocks">
                3
              </div>
          </div>  
     </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/cPh1u6UGmq

This is a perfect example of the reason Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid. It can be evenly divided into halves, thirds or quarters. 16 works for quarters and halves, but not thirds.